# Init GValue for a struct

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I am trying to get a `GdkRGBA` from a `GValue`, but I am unable to init a `GValue` with such a type.

I tried the following code:

```
GValue value;
g_value_init(value, G_TYPE_OBJECT);
gtk_style_context_get_property(style_context, "color", STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &value);
```

But I get the following error:

> cannot initialize GValue with type 'GdkRGBA', the value has already been initialized as 'GObject'

I tried many of the other `G_TYPE_*`, but I get a similar error.

How can I initialize a `GValue` with a type `GdkRGBA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the call to `g_value_init` altogether—judging by the error message it seems `gtk_style_context_get_property` wants to initialize the `GValue` on its own.

Also, I note there is [a separate method defined on `GtkStyleContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-get-color) specifically for retrieving the foreground colour, so this may be a suitable (or preferable) alternative:

```
GdkRGBA color;
gtk_style_context_get_color(style_context, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &color);
```

Comment: That's not what the error says. It doesn't say it wants to init the GValue. It says the user gave a GValue init'd to the wrong type. You can't set a GValue to a value of a type it doesn't already have. `GdkRGBA` is not a `GObject`. I'm not sure at all that `GtkStyleContext` will init the `GValue`; certainly, it is not documented as doing so, so it's probably risky to tell users they don't need to init, especially when their problem was just doing the wrong one. They should have used `GDK_TYPE_RGBA`, but it seems they missed that one. But the method you pointed out is nicer; I'll give you that!

Comment: fwiw, I see that in some of my own code, I am just doing `GValue gvalue = G_VALUE_INIT; gtk_style_context_get_property([...], &value);` and this seems to work: the subsequent assertion that `G_VALUE_HOLDS_[type of style property]` works, and I get the correct value. So, `GtkStyleContext` seems happy with that, and at a minimum, I'd say the user should pass at least a zero-initialised GValue, if not one initialised to a specific type - especially not the wrong type!